# Pointer Addition

Tags: c++, pointers

I do not understand why the pointer addition is failing.

```
DWORD *pipebuf=new DWORD[10001];

Command *cr= (Command*)pipebuf;
cr->command=2;
DWORD* rooms=(pipebuf+1); //should work fine..sets the room pointer equal to pipe[2]
*rooms=buff3;  //where buff3=100
```

Yet, the value of pipebuf only contains the value of command, it does not contain the value of buff3.  Yet, when I remove the new keyword it works fine...Why?

DWORD=unsigned_int

Command is a class with a DWORD variable of command..  something like this

```
Class Command {
DWORD command;
}
```

Comment: DWORD=unsigned_int. Command is a class with a DWORD variable of command

Answer (score 2):

The addition moves the pointer forward one, causing it to point at the second DWORD in your array.  `*(pipebuf+1)` is precisely equivalent to `pipebuf[1]`; after your code runs, `*pipebuf` aka `pipebuf[0]` aka `cr->command` is equal to 2, while `*(pipebuf+1)` aka `*rooms` aka `pipebuf[1]` is equal to 100.

Note however that typecasting between pointer types in C++ is often considered bad style and can in many circumstances have undesirable results.  If you are allocating an array of `Command`'s, then use `new Command[...]`; if you want DWORD's, then don't cast into `Command*`.

Sometimes you have to cast pointers between types, but generally you should only do that if you know **exactly** what you're doing and why you can't avoid doing so.

Furthermore, if you do need to, you should either be using `static_cast` (in cases like this) or `dynamic_cast` (in cases where the types are related by inheritance; this usage is much safer generally).

Comment: Yes exactly..*rooms should be equivalent to pipebuf[1] and it should set pipe[1] equal to 100....Yet it fails to do so...Yes I know its bad style but in this situation it's easier to grasp the code.

Comment: What perplexes me the most is that it is fixed by changing it from a dynamic pointer..That is removing the new keyword.

Answer (score 0):

class `Command` is a user defined type and `DWORD` is a primitive data type ( `unsigned int` ). In that case, why doing this -

```
Command *cr= (Command*)pipebuf;
```

---

```
class Command {
    public :     // Added public keyword
    DWORD command;  // DWORD is a typedef for unsigned int as you mentioned.
};  // class definition should end with a semi-colon
```

So, this is the way to do -

```
Command *cr = new Command[10001] ;
DWORD *pipebuf=new DWORD[10001];

// After assigining values to DWORD pointed locations. Then you can do this -

cr->command = pipebuf[0] ; // this sets the value of cr[0].command.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make this a comment, but I can't do code formatting in those.

I ran this code, and the output is "2 100" as expected:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned int DWORD;
class Command {
  public:
    DWORD command;
};

int main()
{
    DWORD buff3 = 100;
    DWORD *pipebuf = new DWORD[10001];
    Command *cr = (Command*)pipebuf;
    cr->command = 2;
    DWORD *rooms = (pipebuf+1);
    *rooms = buff3;

    std::cout << pipebuf[0] << " " << pipebuf[1] << endl;
}
```

AFAICT that's the simplest way you could expand your question into a complete program.

Could you try taking this and adding more stuff from the original code until you get the problem to appear?